# pg_restore error [archiver] unsupported version (1.14) in the file header

Tags: postgresql-11

I read a lot of the answers of the topic, but no solution.

```
>pg_restore --version / pg_restore (PostgreSQL) 11.5

psql --version/ psql (PostgreSQL) 11.5
```

I have made the backup 2 days ago. I have a similar experience with another machine, but i was trying to restore a file created in version 10 in a version 11 PostgreSQL. In this case, the same one, no updates in these 2 days.

All the posts i have read are from the oldest versions.
I cannot believe this will happen every time we create a backup. Do we need to update everything? do some real solutions were found for this one?

The problem may be with Postgis version? i have installed 3.0.1. and according to [postgis support matrix](https://trac.osgeo.org/postgis/wiki/UsersWikiPostgreSQLPostGIS) should be ok.

thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: The **title** should be translated into English, too !!